# Update not working in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code of update.php, I think I write a wrong code but can not find out where I'm doing wrong just tell me can I use if condition like this

EDIT---> i want level1 only update a field which comes in area of level1 other all should be remain same but they get empty when i submit a from one more thing one level user can not see the other level user's  field they hide from him,

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['update'])){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tabl1` WHERE `ID` = ".$_REQUEST['update'];
    $query = mysql_query( $sql );
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    $IndexNo= $_POST['IndexNo'];
    $ZoneID = $_POST['ZoneID'];
    $NameofCoordinator= $_POST['NameofCoordinator'];
    $GridNumber= $_POST['GridNumber'];
    $MobileNumber= $_POST['MobileNumber'];
    $StatusID= $_POST['StatusID'];

    $sql="UPDATE `tabl1` SET `IndexNo` = '$IndexNo',`ZoneID` = '$ZoneID'"; 
    $sql .= if($userName =='admin' || 'level1'){ ",`NameofCoordinator` = '$NameofCoordinator'"; }
    $sql .= if($userName =='admin' || 'level2'){ ", `GridNumber` = '$GridNumber'"; }
    $sql .= if($userName =='admin' || 'level3'){ ",`MobileNumber` = '$MobileNumber'"; }
    $sql .= ",`Keyword` = '$Keyword', `StatusID` = '$StatusID' WHERE `ID` = ".$_REQUEST['update'];
}
```

Comment: where did you wrote mysql_query() for executing the query?

Comment: `Y NO WORK` isn't sufficient description. Please, add error that you're getting and also what is the result?

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="UPDATE `table1` SET `IndexNo` = '$IndexNo',`ZoneID` = '$ZoneID'"; 
            $sql .= if($userName =='admin' || 'level1'){ ",`NameofCoordinator` = '$NameofCoordinator',`RegistrationSurveyDate` = '$RegistrationSurveyDate'"; }
            $sql .= if($userName =='admin' || 'level2'){ ", `GridNumber` = '$GridNumber',`ESRCommandArea` = '$ESRCommandArea'"; }
            $sql .= if($userName =='admin' || 'level3'){ ",`MobileNumber` = '$MobileNumber', `LandlineNumber` = '$LandlineNumber', `ConnectionCategory` = '$ConnectionCategory'"; }
            $sql .= ",`Keyword` = '$Keyword', `StatusID` = '$StatusID', `Comment`='$Comment' WHERE `ID` = ".$_REQUEST['update'];
```

Add on the end

> mysql_query($sql);

Any errors ?

Answer (score 1):

replace it

```
$sql="UPDATE `table1` SET `IndexNo` = '$IndexNo',`ZoneID` = '$ZoneID'"; 
            if($userName =='admin' || 'level1')
            {
                 $sql .= ",`NameofCoordinator` = '$NameofCoordinator',`RegistrationSurveyDate` = '$RegistrationSurveyDate'";
            }

            if($userName =='admin' || 'level2')
            { 
                $sql .= ", `GridNumber` = '$GridNumber',`ESRCommandArea` = '$ESRCommandArea'";
            }
            if($userName =='admin' || 'level3')
            { 
                $sql .= ",`MobileNumber` = '$MobileNumber', `LandlineNumber` = '$LandlineNumber', `ConnectionCategory` = '$ConnectionCategory'"; 
            }
                $sql .= ",`Keyword` = '$Keyword', `StatusID` = '$StatusID', `Comment`='$Comment' WHERE `ID` = ".$_REQUEST['update'];


myql_query($sql) or die();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE `ocwconnections` SET `IndexNo` = '$IndexNo',`ZoneID` = '$ZoneID'
        `NameofCoordinator` = if($userName =='admin' || $userName == 'level1' ,'$NameofCoordinator' , ''),
        `GridNumber`    = if($userName =='admin' || $userName == 'level2' ,'$GridNumber' , ''),   
        `MobileNumber` = if($userName =='admin' || $userName == 'level3' ,$MobileNumber ,''),
        `Keyword` = '$Keyword', `StatusID` = '$StatusID' WHERE `ID` = ".$_REQUEST['update'] ");
```

Or if you wanna do it separated like you done:

```
$sql=mysql_query("UPDATE `ocwconnections` SET `IndexNo` = '$IndexNo',`ZoneID` = '$ZoneID' ";
$sql .= " `NameofCoordinator` = if($userName =='admin' || $userName == 'level1' ,'$NameofCoordinator' , ''), ";
$sql .= " `GridNumber`    = if($userName =='admin' || $userName == 'level2' ,'$GridNumber' , ''), ";   
$sql .= " `MobileNumber` = if($userName =='admin' || $userName == 'level3' ,$MobileNumber ,''), ";
$sql .= " `Keyword` = '$Keyword', `StatusID` = '$StatusID' WHERE `ID` = ".$_REQUEST['update'] ");
```

**NOTE:** that i have putted `''` to be updated in every column when the if statment  doesnt return true in condition , you can change it to what ever value you want to update.

EDIT>

```
   $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE `ocwconnections` SET `IndexNo` = '$IndexNo',`ZoneID` = '$ZoneID' , 
    `NameofCoordinator` = if($userName =='admin' || $userName == 'level1' ,'$NameofCoordinator' , `NameofCoordinator`),
    `GridNumber`    = if($userName =='admin' || $userName == 'level2' ,'$GridNumber' , `GridNumber`),   
    `MobileNumber` = if($userName =='admin' || $userName == 'level3' ,$MobileNumber ,`MobileNumber`),
    `Keyword` = '$Keyword', `StatusID` = '$StatusID' WHERE `ID` = ".$_REQUEST['update'] ");
```

Comment: i want level1 only update a field which comes in area of level1 other all should be remain same but they get empty when i submit a from one more thing one level user can not see the other level user's  field they hide from him,

Comment: @user3283373 i guess i got what you want try my edited answer (last query)

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all, instead of assigning your post data to variables, use as they are.
2) use ternary operator instead of your if condition

Check Below Code

if(!empty($_REQUEST['update'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tabl1` WHERE `ID` = ".$_REQUEST['update'];
    $query = mysql_query( $sql );
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);

```
$sql = "UPDATE `tabl1` SET `IndexNo` = '$_POST['IndexNo']',`ZoneID` = '$_POST['ZoneID']'"; 
$sql.= ($userName =='admin' || 'level1')?(",`NameofCoordinator` = '$_POST[\'NameofCoordinator\']'")
      :(($userName =='admin' || 'level2')?(`GridNumber` = '$_POST[\'GridNumber\']'")
      :(($userName =='admin' || 'level3')?(`MobileNumber` = '$_POST[\'MobileNumber\']'"):''));
$sql .= ",`Keyword` = '$Keyword', `StatusID` = '$_POST[\'StatusID\']' WHERE `ID` = ".$_REQUEST['update'];
```

}